# php header within iframe

Tags: php, iframe, header

I have developed a web app that has a main page and an iframe within it. Most of the action occurs within the iframe. It all works fine on my localhost, but when I uploaded it to the web, all of the page redirects within the iframe stopped working. An example of the code is:

```
header("Location: contacts_controller.php?Action=show_contact&Contact_ID=1");
exit();
```

I've tried relative paths, absolute paths, with `http://` and without, and `$_SERVER` and nothing works. Like I said, the snippet above works fine on my local machine but not when it is online.

Comment: frames\iframes generally not recommended anymore

Comment: Turn on warnings. See if anything is being echoed before the header() in your production code.

Comment: Thanks Drakes! Yes you were right. I first spent a whole day getting rid of iframes because everyone hates iframes. That didn't fix it. I didn't think you were right because I generally do see warnings. But I changed error reporting to "error_reporting(E_ALL)." From that, I learned that the headers were being modified elsewhere in the code. I tracked down the location, fixed the code, and that seems to have worked. I still don't understand why the headers had been modified. I think there was just some whitespace after "?>" Should've listened to you first, though I am glad to be rid of iframes.

Comment: @user3232390 Inadvertant whitespace - my goto suspect for headers already written. Next, see what's happening with error reporting. Glad you got it working!